# If average of an $L^1$ function is in S, then does $f \in S$?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $f \in L^1(\mu)$. Given a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ which is not closed, if $ \frac{1}{\mu(E)} \int_E f \, d\mu \in S$ for all $E \in \mathcal{M}$, then does it imply that $f(x) \in S$ for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$?

I intend to disprove the above statement, tried elementary functions but not getting any counter.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean, from "Given" it seems $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, but then you say something about $f \in S$

Comment: I think you mean to say that $f(x) \in S$ for $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$.  The result *is* true if $S$ is closed.

Comment: @demi: I’m pretty sure he is taking an open set in $\mathcal M$.

Comment: "Open set in $\cal M$" doesn't make sense. $S$ is an open set in the codomain of $f$, either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusion, $f(x)\in S$ for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$ and  as @UmbertoP. said this result is true for a closed set, I would like to have a counterexample for the same result for open sets.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Do you know of any counter?